# Dynamically load different text blocks in wpf and set context menu for all of them

Tags: wpf

We have a requirement to dynamically load textblocks in a view based on the result retirived from the database.

for e.g: if count is returned as "5"

I need to show 5 textblocks ,we also need to set "context menu" on textblocks.

If user right clicks on the context menu, he has a option to load "more textblocks" by clicking show other details .wanted to know the best way how to accomplish this.

Regards

chaitu

---

Thanks for your mail,
We have a requirement to show different data on different context menu of different textblocks. and the context menu has the header , belwo which it has "Name" "Phonenumber

fore.g: 
 **Textblock A**,
which has contextmenu

### ABC

Adam   "123456"

### Steve   "56789"

Load More details

**for TextBlock B,**

### DEF

Sachin   "9999"

### Rahul    "8976"

Load More details

this should be the display.
When User clicks on "Load More details" ,
On right hand side of currentTextBlocks , another set of TextBlocks should get displayed .

Regards
chaitu

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Observablecollection binded to an ItemTemplate. For example:

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="More Detail" Click="LoadMoreDetail" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and codebehind

```
public ObservableCollection<string> myTextBlocks { get; set; }
private void LoadModel()
{
   myTextBlocks = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   // HERE IMPLEMENTS YOUR DB LOGIC TO LOAD
   myTextBlocks.Add("1");
   myTextBlocks.Add("2");
   myTextBlocks.Add("3");

   this.DataContext = myTextBlocks;
}
private void LoadMoreDetail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   myTextBlocks.Add("more detail");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your mail, We have a requirement to show different data on different context menu of different textblocks. and the context menu has the header , belwo which it has "Name" "Phonenumber

fore.g: Textblock A, which has contextmenu

ABC
Adam "123456"

Steve "56789"
Load More details

for TextBlock B,

DEF
Sachin "9999"

Rahul "8976"
Load More details

this should be the display. When User clicks on "Load More details" , On right hand side of currentTextBlocks , another set of TextBlocks should get displayed .

Regards chaitu

Comment: Can you explain better please? Does the context menu have binded content and a "load more" button? I give you an example with a a simple ObservableCollection of string; if you provide your object model I can hel you further.

Comment: Yes the Context menu should get bind to an itemsource which has Name,PhoneNumber ,Show More details .I have an object which has Name,PhoneNumber etc. The TextBlock is binded to this object and the ContextMenu will also be binded to same , when user clicks on showmore details a new set of textblocks should get dispalyed on the right.please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @deathrace.dj Turn your `ObservableCollection<string>` into an `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>`, where `SomeClass` contains properties for `Text` and `ObservableCollection<SomeOtherClass>`, and `SomeOtherClass` contains a `DisplayValue` and an `ICommand`. Then you can bind your `TextBlock.Text` to `Text`, and build a `ContextMenu` for it based on the collection of `SomeOtherClass` objects, with the `Content` bound to `DisplayValue` and the `Command` bound to the `ICommand`

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have the same issue. I am able to load the first  set of textblocks(binding the itemsource) after which If I do a right click on the textblock context menu, the other set of (other Itemsource) textblocks are not getting loaded.